# Wrong color value in Interface Builder when using Named Color Set

Tags: xcode, colors, interface-builder

I made a named color set called grey2 values 233,233,233 in assets.

But when I use the named color in Storyboard, the value becomes 228,228,228.

It causes many problem in case of I also set the color value from my code.